# Get info from API on Windows Phone 8 using JSON

Tags: c#, json, windows-phone-8

I am new to Windows Phone development and I don't know what to do.
I have an API that gives value for a football club.
This is my server-side code:

```
public function getInfostradaTable()
{
    $season = wp_cache_get('seasonId', 'infostradaOverview');
    if ($season == false)
    {         
        $this->getEditionInfo();
        $season = wp_cache_get('seasonId', 'infostradaOverview');
        if ($season == false)
        {
            return NULL;
        }
    }
    $table = wp_cache_get('table', 'infostradaTable');
    if ($table != false)
    {
        return $table;
    }
    else 
    {                
        $this->getTableInfo();
        $table = wp_cache_get('table', 'infostradaTable');
        if ($table != false)
        {
            return $table;
        }
        else
        {
            return NULL;
        }
    }           
}
```

This is a part of the jsonrpc file.
How can I connect with the API and get the values using JSON?

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at [Windows.Data.Json namespace](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/windows.data.json.Aspx).